WebAuthenticator in .net MAUI using refresh_token
I'm following this guide to implement the web authentication in a .net Maui application and it works well.
Where I'm struggling is, how to implement the call back to the backend if the access_token expires. The target is, so fare I understand the principle, the use the refresh_token to request a new access_token by the issuer (google, Microsoft or Apple).
My current plan is to send the scheme and the refresh_token to a backend method which request the access_token by the issuer.
The challenge is, I have no idea how to implement the request. I found several code snippets in the web, they look well, but for my understanding, outdated.
Does anyone have already implemented this approach (I'm pretty sure yes) and can share the code or a link where I can find additional information ?

Do check out the Duende.AccessTokenManagement project for token management. There is not built-in support for this, so either use this library or make your own library.
Here's a sample method to get a new access token in ASP.NET Core:
   /// <summary>
    /// Get a new access token and refresh token from IdentitytServer and update it in the cookie    
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string? GetNewAccessToken()
    {
        var refreshToken = HttpContext.Session.GetString("refresh_token") ?? "";

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(refreshToken))
            return "";

        var data = new RefreshCodeFlowLogin();

        var url = new Url($"{Settings.OIDCServer}/connect/token");

        //Console.WriteLine("Refresh token " + refreshToken);
        //Console.WriteLine("ClientId " + data?.client_id?.Trim());
        //Console.WriteLine("ClientSecret " + data?.client_secret?.Trim());

        var client = new HttpClient();
        TokenResponse? response = client.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(new RefreshTokenRequest
        {
            Address = url,

            ClientId = data?.client_id?.Trim() ?? "",
            ClientSecret = data?.client_secret?.Trim(),

            RefreshToken = refreshToken
        }).Result;

        //Console.WriteLine("new Refresh token " + response.RefreshToken);
        //Console.WriteLine("new access token " + response.AccessToken);

        //Save the access and refresh the token in the session cookie
        Request.HttpContext.Session.SetString("access_token", response.AccessToken ?? "");
        Request.HttpContext.Session.SetString("refresh_token", response.RefreshToken ?? "");
        Request.HttpContext.Session.SetString("expires_in", response.ExpiresIn.ToString() ?? "");

        return response?.AccessToken;
    }
}


Thanks Tore, I had some progress with by using your code, currently after a logout, the WebAuthenticator caches the credential somehow and start the the login with the old credentials as soon the app opens the WebAuthenticator.

Hi  @Jean, what platform did you encounter this problem on? Is there any log about this problem?

Hi Jessie, I‘m using Android, API Version 31, net8-android.

Hi @Jean, is there any log about this problem?

Hi Jessie, no log not sure how to log the webauthenticator. Do you have some advice how I can log the issue?

For this problem, you can post a new issue here.
